# Is it possible to Export or Package a Learning Path into a Dynamics 365 Solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have just been playing around with Learning Paths in Dynamics, and now I am wondering if there is any way to either Export/Import them, publish them into another tenant, or embed them into a solution.

I like the idea of being able to use them to guide users through new features, but from an initial play it doesn't look like I can (hopefully I am wrong). I tried adding Guest Access and putting the Guest User in the Learning Path Authors group, but that doesn't seem to let me Publish out to it.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/create-guided-help-learning-path#how-does-learning-path-work-with-multiple-organizations);

> ## How does Learning Path work with multiple organizations?
>
> When you publish Learning Path content, you can use Publishing
> Environments to control which organizations associated with the tenant
> your content is published to. To publish different content to
> different organizations, create multiple publishing environments and
> add each organization to one or more of them.

Or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/create-guided-help-learning-path#export-and-import-learning-path-content);

> ## Export and import Learning Path content
>
> You can export content that you create, perhaps to share with an
> author of another organization or to make backup copies. The export
> feature creates a compressed .zip file that contains the .json files
> used for your content in Learning Path. There will be one folder in
> the .zip file for each selected Learning Path Sidebar or Guided Task.
>
> ### Export your Learning Path content
>
> In the Content Library, select the check box next to the content you want to export. ... You can export content without checking it in. ... Select Manage at the top of the page, and then select Export. ... Select the option you want to use for saving the generated .zip file, and then select a file name and location.
>
> ### Import your Learning Path content
>
> In the Content Library, select Manage, and then select Import. ... Select Browse to select the previously exported file that you want to import, or drag the file to the Drag controls here box in the dialog box. .. Confirm that the file name displayed is the file you want to import, and then select Import. ... In the confirmation dialog box, select OK.